# converting hex decimal representation with ASCII

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to replace hex representation (#..) with its representation in ASCII in a pdf file

```
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\hello-world-malformed.pdf","rb") as file1:
    stuff = file1.read()
stuff = re.sub("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})",lambda m:unichr(int(m.groups()[0],16)),stuff)
with open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\hello-world-malformed.pdf","wb") as file1:
    file1.write(stuff)
file1 = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\hello-world-malformed.pdf")
print file1.read()
```

when I run it using "Geany" it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "testing.py", line 31, in main
    stuff = re.sub("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})",lambda m:unichr(int(m.groups()[0],16)),stuff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 239: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Why the `unichr()` when you are using byte strings everywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `unichr()`; it produces a unicode string with one character. Don't mix Unicode strings and byte strings (binary data), as this'll trigger implicit encoding or decoding. Here an implicit decode is triggered and fails.

Your codepoints are limited to values 0-255, so a simple `chr()` will do:

```
stuff = re.sub("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})", lambda m: chr(int(m.group(0), 16)), stuff)
```

Comment: @user3569815: I follow the `python` tag already, don't ping random users on their posts for attention, please. Your post is barely 7 minutes old.